# Google Maps API v3: How to remove an Event Listener?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I remove the 'bounds_changed' Event listener in [Google Maps API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/events.html)?

```
google.maps.event.removeListener(_???_);
```

Comment: I think I found what you were looking for. It was the 3rd event function in API docs.

Comment: I feel your pain. You would think this documentation would be on http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html but its not. Grrrr

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Usually you can find answers to such questions in Google Maps API documentation.

As Andrew said, addListener returns a handle which you can use later to remove the listener. That's because a single event can have many listeners and to remove them you must save a reference to each of attached listeners.

There's also a function which removes all of the listeners at the same time:

```
clearListeners(instance:Object, eventName:string);
//In your case:
google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'bounds_changed');
```

[Here's the Google Maps API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MapsEventListener) where you can read about it.

Comment: So will this remove ONLY the bounds_changed event?

Comment: What's the pro/con of using this method vs Andrews method?

Comment: This removes all listeners from the bounds_changed event. While Andrew's method removes one. If you don't want to store the handle somewhere and you only have to worry about 1 listener for given event then this is the way to go.

Comment: As I said events can have many listeners, but it seems like you're just using 1 in your code. If you'll understand that concept you will see the different uses for both functions. Also see the link I provided, it has nice explanations for both of those functions.

Comment: This is currently throwing errors. Looks like it's been depreciated.

Comment: @AndyM As far as I can tell it's not deprecated. If you follow the documentation link then you can still find the function. Even if you go to experimental (next version) documentation the function and event is still there. You may want to check your code again.

Comment: Figured it out. `google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'idle')` works. But `map.clearListeners('idle')` doesn't. That syntax works for everything else in the API (`.addListener`, etc). Odd.

Answer (score 100):

addListener returns a handle which you can later pass to removeListener:

```
var listenerHandle = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {

google.maps.event.removeListener(listenerHandle);
```

Comment: So there is no longer static variables for the listeners?

Comment: Listeners need to be removed one by one.  You can't unbind them all ala jQuery.  I know because I thought the same and got confused on this point too.  I eventually worked it out and the pseudo-code above roughly illustrates how I did it.

Comment: Look at my answer, I think it's a better solution.

Comment: Drat! Yours *is* a better answer.

Comment: Where is this documented? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Better answer for me, that's removing only the event listener we created and it does not impact the other scripts

Comment: Better answer for two reasons.  Only, removes actual listener.  Also, doesn't have the snarky "You can find it in the API docs' comment.

Answer (score 21):

This seems to work in the current release.

```
var listenerHandle = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    // Handler code.
});
listenerHandle.remove();
```

Comment: And the nice thing about this approach is that `listenerHandler.remove()` works for data-layer listeners as well -- i.e. `google.maps.data.addListener` -- since there is NO `google.maps.data.removeListener` method defined.

Comment: Yeap.... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#removing

Answer (score 0):

If you couldnt hold the listener object somehow you could remove listener(s) directly as `google.maps.event.clearListeners(objectListened, 'event');`

Ex: `google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'bounds_changed');`