# How to disable an infowindow in googlemaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Consider the following code that opens an infowindow in google maps:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Question: How can I disable the infowindow from showing if the window width is less than 900px?

I still want the code to work at widths above 900px.

Comment: Test the window width, and [remove the listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544151/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-an-event-listener).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
  var ww = outerWidth || document.body.offsetWidth;
  if(ww > 900){
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
   }
});
```