# Remove google map entirely

Tags: javascript, google-maps

What is the best way to totally remove a Google map and all event listeners? I'm using the Google maps V3 API

I have my map stored in `App.map` object and my div with the map has a class of `map`.

Is there a proper teardown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar answer that might help with the listeners:

[Google Maps API v3: How to remove an Event Listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544151/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-an-event-listener)

If you're using jQuery, .remove() will take the entire DIV out of the DOM.

Hope this helps!