# Add listener after it has been removed on map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

When creating my [Google map markers,](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

I am adding event listeners like so -

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Hi there from Alabama!'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
    infowindow.open(map, marker); // this displays the infowindow on mouseover
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
    infowindow.close(); // this close the infowindow on mouseout
});

marker.addListener('click', function () {
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'mouseout');
    // this removes the mouseout listener when the marker is clicked so that it stays
    // present after mouseout.
});
```

The aforementioned works a treat however I also want to be able to re-add the `mouseout` event after the info window has been closed.

What I tried was adding this to my function -

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout');
    // when the info window is closed the mouseout event is reinstated
    // I also previously added an alert here to make sure it was hit!
});
```

This creates the marker ok, however in action, I am able to click on the marker > mouseout and for the infowindow to stay present > close the infowindow. All desired behaviour.

However on hovering over the marker again, the infowindow shows (as expected) but on hitting the `mouseout` event, I get -

```
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference
```

The error is residing in the Google api JS file so it is very hard to determine what the root of the problem is. How can I reinstate the `mouseout` event properly on the `infowindow` close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have an anonymous function in the event assignment:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
    infowindow.close(); // this close the infowindow on mouseout
});
```

If you create a named function, you can add it like this:

```
function mouseoutHandler() {
    infowindow.close(); // this close the infowindow on mouseout        
}
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', mouseoutHandler);
```

Then, you can remove it...

```
marker.addListener('click', function () {
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'mouseout');
    // this removes the mouseout listener when the marker is clicked so that it stays
    // present after mouseout.
});
```

Later, you simply re-add the event as you did the first time -- because you have a named function, you don't lose the declaration!

---

If you're still hitting an error with the removal of the original event, you [might try being more specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544151/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-an-event-listener):

```
var listenerHandle = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', mouseoutHandler);
// later...
google.maps.event.removeListener(listenerHandle);
```

Comment: Arthur, good answer and I fully understand ours logic, however unfortunately (even with the more specific deceleration) I am still getting the same undefined error on mouseout, any other ideas?