# Limiting number of markers that can be created by clicking using leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am prompting the user to click to create a single point marker on my map. I need to limit this to only one marker (which must be draggable). I have tried using a count variable with a comparison however this condition is not working for me (the user can make many markers - as shown in this image).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var count = 0;
if (count <= 0) { 
map.on('click', function(e){
    count += 1;
    var marker = L.marker(e.latlng,{draggable: true}).addTo(map);
    var lat = e.latlng.lat;
    var lon = e.latlng.lng;
    alert("Lat, Lon : " + lat + ", " + lon);

    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can remove the listener after it is first called. Here is how you could do that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1544151/1552587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply **unbind the `click` event after the first** click via `off`:

```
var onClick = function(e) {
    map.off('click', onClick);

    var marker = L.marker(e.latlng,{draggable: true}).addTo(map);
    var lat = e.latlng.lat;
    var lon = e.latlng.lng;
    alert("Lat, Lon : " + lat + ", " + lon);
};

map.on('click', onClick);
```

---

More info in [the Leaflet docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#evented).